# Call C# code-behind method with a <li> onclick

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, methods

I got a li - list, one with an onclick:

```
<ul class="tabs"> 
    <li><a href="#tab1">Foobar_1</a></li> 
    <li onclick="doMethod"><a href="#tab2">Foobar_2</a></li> 
    <li><a href="#tab3">Foobar_3</a></li> 
    <li><a href="#tab4">Foobar_4</a></li>
</ul>
```

Now, the method I want to call when clicked on a tab (the li's), updates an UpdatePanel, so a gridview is shown.

I know it must have something to do with AJAX, but I ain't got a clue how to move on now...

so basically: how to call a c# method using AJAX?

Answer (score 8):

```
<li runat="server" OnClick="DoMyOnClickCall">....</li>
```

Then

```
public void DoMyOnClickCall(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   // sender is the li dom element you'll need to cast it though.
}
```

To expand: **(Update)**

`sender` is an object that represents the `<li>...</li>` in HTML. It's called something like `HtmlControl`.

You'll need to cast `sender` to that type.

```
var myLI = (HtmlControl)sender;
// do stuff with `myLI`
```

Comment: I thought he wanted a callback not a postback

Comment: I get a JScript runtime error... it says "DoMyOnClickCall" is undefined...
well, I really got the c# method though

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "casting the li dom element"?

Comment: I get an invalidCastException... The ASP type object could not be cast to a HTMLControl

Comment: I don't remember the exact control that `<li>` transform into. You could find out by outputting `sender.GetType().FullName` and then you'll know.

Answer (score 1):

Also, you can call the method from client side by:

1. declare your method as public static bool
2. put attribute  [WebMethod] for this method
3. Call the method from js

Sample code:

```
<script language="javascript">
    function MyClientFunction() {
        var liElement = $get("liElement").value;
        PageMethods.doMethod(liElement,OnSuccess, OnFailure);
    }

    function OnSuccess(result) {
        if(result) {
            alert("Some error message!");
        }
    }

    function OnFailure(error) {

    }
</script>
```

Comment: I'm not sure if you had `void static` or `static bool` in your first point (based on the edit history). All I fixed was the code formatting which wasn't showing up properly when appearing after the numbered list. Add some text after it and it works. Please review in case I edited after you made an edit.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the formating. I meant static bool, but I'll fix it. Thanks for pointing this.

Comment: How do I put [WebMethod] as attribute to my c# method? Do I need a special reference?

Comment: It is declared in `[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]`. You can find more information here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/byxd99hx(VS.71).aspx